# Rails 3 routes and using GET to create clean URLs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, get, routes, ruby-on-rails-3

I am a little confused with the routes in Rails 3 as I am just starting to learn the language. I have a form generated here:

```
  <%= form_tag towns_path, :method => "get" do %>
    <%= label_tag :name, "Search for:" %>
    <%= text_field_tag :name, params[:name] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
  <% end %>
```

Then in my routes:

```
  get "towns/autocomplete_town_name"
  get "home/autocomplete_town_name"

  match 'towns' => 'towns#index'
  match 'towns/:name' => 'towns#index'

  resources :towns, :module => "town"
  resources :businesses, :module => "business"

  root :to => "home#index"
```

So why when submitting the form do I get the URL:

> /towns?utf8=✓&name=townname&commit=Search

So the question is how do I make that url into a clean url like:

> /towns/townname

Thanks,

Andrew

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the last bit stating what I expect the url to appear as.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly the routes

```
resources :towns do
  post 'townname', :on => :collection
end
```

or

```
match "town/:name" => "towns#index", :as => :townname, :via => [:post], :constraints => { :name => /[A-Za-z]/ }
```

and the form

```
<%= form_tag townname_towns_path, :method => "post" do %>
  <%= label_tag :name, "Search for:" %>
  <%= text_field_tag :name, params[:name] %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Article about difference between POST and GET http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_difference_between_get_and_post_method_in_HTTP

Comment: Should this not be possible with GET to ensure any searches can be stored as bookmarks? Thank you for posting this solution!

Comment: Well if you have GET request in URL you'll always have parameter-value pair so request have to be POST try new route I've just added

Comment: Just got back to this and I see what you mean, I forgot where I read about the GET request but it was more just saying to redirect to create them. Which will lead me to my next question on here, thank you for the reply as this works fine : )

Comment: Can somebody please tell me what that :as do there? Docs?